# Susy parameters are producing an incorrect @container width

Tags: susy-compass

The following -

```
$total-columns: 12;
$column-width: 60px;
$gutter-width: 20px;
$grid-padding: 10px;
$container-style: static;
.centre { @include container; }
```

Produces this css -

```
width: 1020px;
padding-left: 10px;
padding-right: 10px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

Even though all the columns within that container are worked out correctly. So

```
#logo { @include span-columns( 5, 12 ); }
```

correctly produces an element of width 380px and a margin of 20px to the right.

```
nav { @include span-columns( 7 omega, 12 ); }
```

then correctly creates an element of 540px and places it to the right of #logo with no margin. However, the parent #centre container for these elements is 1020px wide instead of 940px wide.

Can anybody shed any light on why this may be?

Thanks in advance.

[UPDATE]

adding

```
$container-width: 1140px;
```

correctly produces

```
width: 1120px;
```

however, adding

```
$container-width: 960px;
```

has the effect of causing compass to cease watching files. It shows me 'change detected...' but then fails to the 'overwrite...' command. I have to cancel compass and run compass watch again after removing the

```
$container-width: 960px;
```

Very odd!

Comment: What version of Susy, and what other settings do you have? I can't recreate this. I get `940px` by default (which is right for `box-sizing: content-box;`), and `960px` if I use `border-box-sizing`. I can't reproduce the failing-to-compile bug either.

Answer (score 0):

I get the same issue when trying to recreate a classic 960gs 16 column grid:

```
$total-columns: 16;
$column-width: 40px;
$gutter-width: 20px;
$grid-padding: 10px;
```

Produces a container that is `940px` wide, not `960px` wide.

susy v1.0.5